# How to render the Images in my Card instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to embed various information from my data file (array of objects) in my card instance in the App.js file. The information is all displayed correctly so far.
The problem is that the photos are not displayed. I've already tried by changing the path on import. And moved the images folder from src to public. Unfortunately, neither did anything. Where else could the problem lie here?
Is there an error in the .map?

Thank you for your tip.

```
import './App.css';
import Card from './components/Card';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Data from "./components/Data";


function App() {

  const cards = Data.map(item => {
    return (
      <Card 
      img={item.coverImg}
      rating={item.stats.rating}
      reviewCount={item.stats.reviewCount}
      location={item.location}
      title={item.title}
      price={item.price}
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      {cards}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Life Lessons with Katie Zaferes",
        description: "I will share with you what I call \"Positively Impactful Moments of Disappointment.\" Throughout my career, many of my highest moments only came after setbacks and losses. But learning from those difficult moments is what gave me the ability to rise above them and reach my goals.",
        price: 136,
        coverImg: "katie-zaferes.png",
        stats: {
            rating: 5.0,
            reviewCount: 6
        },
        location: "Online",
        openSpots: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Learn Wedding Photography",
        description: "Interested in becoming a wedding photographer? For beginner and experienced photographers alike, join us in learning techniques required to leave the happy couple with memories that'll last a lifetime.",
        price: 125,
        coverImg: "wedding-photography.png",
        stats: {
            rating: 5.0,
            reviewCount: 30
        },
        location: "Online",
        openSpots: 27,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Group Mountain Biking",
        description: "Experience the beautiful Norwegian landscape and meet new friends all while conquering rugged terrain on your mountain bike. (Bike provided!)",
        price: 50,
        coverImg: "mountain-bike.png",
        stats: {
            rating: 4.8,
            reviewCount: 2
        },
        location: "Norway",
        openSpots: 3,
    }
]
```

```
import React from 'react'

function card(props) {
    return (
        <div className="card--footer">
            <img src={props.img}/>
            <p><img src="../images/star.png"></img>{props.rating} ({props.reviewCount}) USA</p>
            <p>{props.title}</p>
            <p><strong>From ${props.price}</strong> / Person</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default card
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding a `"/images/"` before `item.coverImg`, it should work, if your `images` folder is in `public` folder. Like so :

```js
import './App.css';
import Card from './components/Card';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Data from "./components/Data";


function App() {

  const cards = Data.map(item => {
    return (
      <Card 
      img={"/images/"+item.coverImg}
      rating={item.stats.rating}
      reviewCount={item.stats.reviewCount}
      location={item.location}
      title={item.title}
      price={item.price}
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      {cards}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react'

function card(props) {
    return (
        <div className="card--footer">
            <img src={props.img}/>
            <p><img src="/images/star.png"></img>{props.rating} ({props.reviewCount}) USA</p>
            <p>{props.title}</p>
            <p><strong>From ${props.price}</strong> / Person</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default card
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it did not change anything. Neither if the images folder is still in src or in public directory.

Comment: I see, so you have an images folder ? I edited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: Not yet. right now I got my images folder in src. If possible i wanna keep it like that to not cause other problems. In the Card.js file im got <img src={props.img}/> and in my Card instance i got img={"/images/"+item.coverImg}

Comment: Since you are doing some dynamique routing in a `map`, the clean way is to have them in the `public` folder. Otherwise you need to import each image in your array.

Comment: Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/components/Hero.js 5:0-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/airbnb.png' in '/Users/remofurrer/Desktop/Privat/Entwicklung/Projekte/airbnb/src/components'


ERROR in ./src/components/Navbar.js 5:0-57

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../public/images/airbnb-logo.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: You can actually have two `images` folder. One in `src` for images that are related to your array. And one `images` folder in `public`, for the one related to your array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240415/discussion-between-remo-furrer-and-yousoumar).